# PHP, SQL populate info from database based on drop down selection menu

Tags: php, sql

I have managed to pull data from SQL Database into drop-down selection menu and added a submit button. However I am struggling to populate further data from DB(e.g- age, ID) from other(or even the same) table when user clicks submit.

I would like the user to be able to select customerName from dropdown menu and submit it.
When "submit" button is clicked, other(e.g. age, ID) details linked to the specific customerName (e.g-Rob) should be populated from database and displayed.
Please help. I'm new to php and spent hours on this silly thing. I am only allowed to use php, sql and html.

Many thanks.

dropdown.php  -original version(didn't work)

```
<?php

include "db.php"; // Database connection 


$sql="SELECT customerName FROM customers"; 


echo "<select name=customers value=''>Customer Name</option>"; 

foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){

echo "<option value=$row[customerName]>$row[customerName]</option>"; 



}

echo "</select>";

?>

<form id= method="post" action = "iNeedHelpWithThisFile.php">
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
</body>
```

dropdown.php  -updated version

```
<?php
?>


<form id= method="post" action = "iNeedHelpWithThisFile.php">
<select name="customerName">Customer Name</option> 
<?php
include "db.php"; 
$sql="SELECT `customerName` FROM `customers`"; 
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){
  echo "<option value=\"".$row['customerName']."\">".$row['customerName']."</option>"; 
}
?>

</select>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

db.php

```
<?php
// to connect database 
define('DB_NAME', 'clients');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or
        die ("Cannot connect");
        echo  "Connected to Clients";
?>
```

iNeedHelpWithThisFile.php
echo statements- age, name , id are not being executed

```
<?php

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo "</pre>";

include('db.php');
echo "<br />";

$customerName = $_POST['submit'];


if(array_key_exists('customerName', $_REQUEST ))
{

    // not sure if there's an issue with intval..?
    $customerName = intval($_REQUEST['customerName']);

    echo("Customer: $customerName <br />");

if ($customerName)
{

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers where customerName= ?";  //
    // $conn -defined in db.php
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql))
    {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $customerName);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $queryresult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    }
    else {
          echo "Could not fetch results!";
           }


    if ($queryresult) 
    {
        if ($currentrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {

            $name = $currentrow['customerName'];
            $ID =  $currentrow['customerID'];
            $age  = $currentrow['age'];


           // these statements are not being executed
            echo "Customer Name: $name <br />";
            echo "Customer ID: $ID <br />";
            echo "Age: $age <br />";
    }
}

    else {
        echo "<p>Customer not in the database</p>";
        }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: try this  : echo "<option value=\"".$row['customerName']."\">".$row['customerName']."</option>";

Comment: you have no value='' in the select tag

Comment: the select must be inside the form

Comment: `<form id=` < that's incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

all in all :

```
<form id= method="post" action = "iNeedHelpWithThisFile.php">
<select name="customers">Customer Name</option> 
<?php
include "db.php"; 
$sql="SELECT `customerName` FROM `customers`"; 
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['customerName']."\">".$row['customerName']."</option>"; 
}
?>

</select>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

or if you like the short php tag :

```
<php
include "db.php"; 
$sql="SELECT `customerName` FROM `customers`"; 
?>

<form id="main" method="post" action = "iNeedHelpWithThisFile.php">
<select name="customers">Customer Name</option>

<?php foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){ ?>
  <option value="<?=$row['customerName'];?>"><?=$row['customerName'];?></option>

<?php } ?>

</select>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

if you want to submit also **age** and **ID** together with th **customername** you go like this:

```
<php
include "db.php"; 
$sql="SELECT `age`, `ID`, `customerName` FROM `customers`"; 
?>

<form id= method="post" action = "iNeedHelpWithThisFile.php">
<select name="customers">Customer Name</option>

<?php foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){
 $conc=base64_encode($row['age']."|".$row['ID']."|".$row['customerName']); ?>
  <option value="<?=$conc;?>"><?=$row['customerName'];?></option>
<?php } ?>

</select>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

and in **iNeedHelpWithThisFile.php** you go like this

```
$c = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['customers']);
$c = base64_decode($c);

$name = explode("|",$c)[2];
$ID =  explode("|",$c)[1];
$age  = explode("|",$c)[0];

// these statements are not being executed
echo "Customer Name: $name <br />";
echo "Customer ID: $ID <br />";
echo "Age: $age <br />";
```

Comment: Short tag? `<php` isn't short tag if that's what you meant. Edit: Oh I see what you meant. You left out the `?` for `<php`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Max Muster however I still haven't been able to solve the initial problem..The other fields from DB- age and ID are not being populated after submit button is clicked

Comment: how does your table look like ? what columns do you have ? and what columns do you want to submit.

Comment: At the moment I’m keeping customers table very simple to get things working. Table customers consists of the following columns- customerName(varchar), age(int) and customerID(int).

Comment: Please can you provide full code for iNeedHelpWithThisFile.php  as I can't get this to work. Many thanks :)

Comment: Please come here https://t.me/ecxod and tell me exactly what you want